# How to add new "Unreconciled Entries" filter for "Customer Statement Report" in odoo7

Tags: openerp-7

In Accounting -> Customers -> Customer Statement Report ,
I want to add one more filter "Unreconciled Entries" below the already existing "Unreconciled Entries" filter.And want to add this by inheritance which is having functionality same as available one.

For this I override "set_context"(from third_party_ledger class) method written for "Unreconciled Entries".But it is not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you be more clear? Give us a structure

Comment: @Ajay, we are having filter for "Unreconciled Entries" which filter out for unrecociled entries.I want to same filter below available filter.So for this filter context is set from third_party_ledger class.I override this method and and conditon for custom filter as,                                                         if data['form']['filter'] == 'new_custom_filter':
            self.reconcil = False           Thanks Ajay